# How to read the same file byte by byte asynchronously from within a few threads?

Tags: c, asynchronous, posix

I am trying to read a file with aio.h byte by byte using aio_read with a number of threads. But I don't know if I am on the right track since there are not so many stuff to read on the Internet.

I have just created a `worker` function to pass it to my threads. And also as an argument to pass to the thread, I created a struct called `thread_arguments` and I pass a few necessary arguments in it, which will be needed for `aiocb` such as `offset`, `file_path` to open, `buffer size`, and `priority`.

I can read a file with one thread from start to end successfully. But when it comes to reading a file as chunks from within a few threads, I couldn't make it. And I am not even sure if I can do that with `aio->reqprio` without using semaphores or mutexes. (Trying to open a file from within a few threads at the same time?)

How can I read a few number of bytes from within a few threads asynchronously?

Let's say the file contains "foobarquax" and we have three threads using aio library.

Then first one should read "foo",

the second should read "bar" and

the last one should read "quax" asynchronously.

You can see screenshots of issues regarding running it with multiple threads [on here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxxca.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // open -> file descriptor O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct thread_args {
    char *source_path;
    char *destination_path;
    long int buffer_size;
    long int buffer_size_last; // buffer size for the last thread in case there is a remainder.
    long int offset;
    int priority;
} t_args;


void *worker(void *thread_args) {


    t_args *arguments = (t_args *) thread_args;


    struct aiocb *aiocbRead;

    aiocbRead = calloc(1, sizeof(struct aiocb));

    aiocbRead->aio_fildes = open(arguments->source_path, O_RDONLY);

    if (aiocbRead->aio_fildes == -1) {
        printf("Error");

    }

    printf("opened on descriptor %d\n", aiocbRead->aio_fildes);

    aiocbRead->aio_buf = malloc(sizeof(arguments->buffer_size));
    aiocbRead->aio_offset = arguments->offset;
    aiocbRead->aio_nbytes = (size_t) arguments->buffer_size;
    aiocbRead->aio_reqprio = arguments->priority;

    int s = aio_read(aiocbRead);

    if (s == -1) {
        printf("There was an error");
    }

    while (aio_error(aiocbRead) == EINPROGRESS) {}

    printf("Bytes read %ld", aio_return(aiocbRead));

    close(aiocbRead->aio_fildes);

    for (int i = 0; i < arguments->buffer_size ; ++i) {
        printf("%c\n", (*((char *) aiocbRead->aio_buf + i)));
    }
}

// Returns a random alphabetic character
char getrandomChar() {


    int letterTypeFlag = (rand() % 2);

    if (letterTypeFlag)
        return (char) ('a' + (rand() % 26));
    else
        return (char) ('A' + (rand() % 26));
}

void createRandomFile(char *source, int numberofBytes) {

    FILE *fp = fopen(source, "w");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofBytes; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%c", getrandomChar());
    }

    fclose(fp);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *source_path = argv[1];
    char *destination_path = argv[2];
    long int nthreads = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);


    // Set the seed.
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Get random number of bytes to write to create the random file.
    int numberofBytes = 10 + (rand() % 100000001);

    // Create a random filled file at the source path.
    createRandomFile(source_path, 100);

    // Calculate the payload for each thread.
    long int payload = 100 / nthreads;
    long int payloadLast = payload + 100 % nthreads;

    // Create a thread argument to pass to pthread.
    t_args *thread_arguments = (t_args *) malloc(nthreads * sizeof(t_args));

    for (int l = 0; l < nthreads; ++l) {

        // Set arguments in the struct.
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->source_path = source_path;
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->destination_path = destination_path;
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->buffer_size = payload;
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->buffer_size_last = payloadLast;
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->offset = l * payload;
        (&thread_arguments)[l]->priority = l;

    }


    pthread_t tID[nthreads];

    // Create pthreads.
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&tID[i], NULL, worker, (void *) &thread_arguments[i]);
    }

    // Wait for pthreads to be done.
    for (int j = 0; j < nthreads; ++j) {
        pthread_join(tID[j], NULL);
    }

    free(thread_arguments);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is reading succesfully if I just call it from one thread but doesn't work if I use it for more than one threads which is what I want.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  It even fails to prototype the function: `createRandomFile()`  Please correct and repost

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the desired command line parameters were actually entered by the user

Comment: the posted code declares (and sets) the variable: `numberofBytes`, then never uses it

Comment: well createRandomFile() just creates a random file at the specified path just to use as a source file for aio_read() but I will add it too.

Comment: Now added the necessary functions I've used. I've changed `numberofBytes` to a constant value just to see the difference. Normally it is the second parameter to `createRandomFile()`

Comment: regarding statements like: `(&thread_arguments)[l]->source_path = source_path;`  exactly what are you expecting these statements to do.  Perhaps you meant: `thread_arguments[i].source_path = source_path;`

Comment: the function: `worker()` should exit via: `pthread_exit( NULL );` rather than just run off the end of the function

Comment: OT: when calling (most) c library function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  for instance when calling `pthread_create()`

Comment: regarding: ` t_args *thread_arguments = (t_args *) malloc(nthreads * sizeof(t_args));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Wow! Again pointers got me. Now everything is fine thank you so much! But how can I make use of aio_reqprio in order my threads to read them in the correct order? If I can do that of course.

Comment: try passing to the thread, as part of the parameter struct, a offset and length into the input file then have the thread use `fseek()` to move to that offset, then read the desired number of bytes.  Then it will not matter which thread instance reads first

Comment: Yes, I actually did that without using `fseek()` just setting the `aio_offset` if that's what you meant but when I want to write whatever each thread read to standard out or let's say to a file then the order gets mixed up.

Comment: that is because of the race condition of several threads trying to write to stdout at the same time.  Suggest using a 'global' mutex the each thread calls `pthread_mutex_lock()` then writes its' data, then calls `pthread_mutex_unlock()`  However, even this just means that each thread can output its' data with out interruption.

Comment: To sequence the writing 'could' be constrained by appropriate calling of 'pthread_cond()'`  (check the spelling) when a specific thread is expected to perform its' output.  Probably that means the `main()` would sequentially call that function with the information on which thread is to continue (from where the thread blocks, waiting for its' blocking condition to be satisfied

Comment: Well then I wonder what `aio_reqprio` is for? I thought we could make use of it here since the definition says If `_POSIX_PRIORITIZED_IO` is defined, and this file supports it, then the asynchronous operation is submitted at a priority equal to that of the calling process minus `aiocbp->aio_reqprio`.

Comment: calling: `aio_reqprio()` has nothing to do with sequencing thread execution

Comment: Well it works even without any use of semaphores or mutexes and I don't have any idea as to why that would work ahah. Though I get this error when I try to run this, would you take a look at it please? https://imgur.com/a/OWROf3o  https://ideone.com/LfQ7lF

It's because of the free() on line 84 I believe but I don't know why.